# Javascript - How to implement a queue without shift()?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and have an queue that is implemented using the push() and shift() methods. But the performance decreases once the length of my queue becomes sufficiently large. Is there an alternative to implementing a queue in JavaScript that does not utilise the shift() method to deque ?

Comment: Have you considered a linked list?

Comment: This is not specific to JavaScript. Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(data_structure)?

Comment: Use `.unshift()` and `.pop()` instead :-)

Comment: out of curiosity, how many items is "sufficiently large" to slowdown?

Comment: @dandavis - each queue element contains a JSON object holding references to jpeg images. I enque each of these objects within my queue and deque them using shift(). I load these images into the DOM ( hope I am using the right terminology here) and when the queue length is over 200 items, my browser renders the images sluggishly. Each JSON object 'points' to 50 jpeg images (1280 x 720) and 1Mb in size. I come from a C (embedded) background and I was trying to understand the performance of javascript when it comes to handling a large number of images.

Comment: @Siva According to you above description, I don't think it's the queue that is slow, 200 item is small for both array and linkedlist. The slow part, is you have 50M image in each queue element, adding so many & large image to browser need network time, your browser also need a large amount of memory, you browser probably will out of memory.I don't understand why you need to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is about what data structure is proper to use.

**The reason your performance is bad is:**
Due to add element at beginning of array, this operation need to modify the whole array.

**Use `Linked List` instead of `Array`:**
In this case, linked list is more proper to use, I guess, you can find a library by google, or if you want to implement by yourself, try to define a `linked list` data structure, then add/remove from it, it's quicker for large queue, because it only modify several pointer, not the whole list.

Comment: `shift()` does *remove* elements at the beginning of the array.

Comment: @Bergi If you have a queue, you will modify(add or remove) element at both end of queue, it doesn't matter which method you use.

Comment: Linked List? Looks like you're talking about Java instead of JS.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté common data structure like linked list is not relevant to specific programming language, you can implement it in c/java/javascript/lisp/ ..., it don't just exists in java, ok?

Comment: @flybird yeah, however I couldn't find your said JS implementation by Google. There are some other implementations around the web, of course. e.g. https://github.com/nzakas/computer-science-in-javascript/blob/master/data-structures/linked-list/linked-list.js

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yeah, maybe it's too simple to be a library ..., I am sure you can implement it by yourself in less that 100 lines code.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Java did implement some beautiful queue with different data structure, for different purpose, we can refer to that when try implement queue by hand.

Comment: @flybird: No, OP did ask for a *queue*, not a [deque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue).

Comment: @Bergi No matter queue or deque, if you use array you need to move the whole array at least in one of the 2 operation: add / remove. It's not a stack, queue need operate on both end.